# expanding a quoted string within another string

Tags: php, javascript

I have two variables containing some html code, and another variable containing code for a html form. I am trying to expand a string within the second to pass it as a parameter to a function, however this causes some errors.

My make popup function is very simple:

```
function popup(htmlcode){
child1 = window.open ("about:blank");
child1.document.write(htmlcode);
child1.document.close(); 
}
```

The code that uses the above function

```
<?php
$blah = "<h1>Well</h1>"; $test = "<h2>Done</h2>";
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="fetchlayers.js"></script>';
$formcode = "<form action=\"process.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data \">
<label for=\"file\">Filename:</label>
<input type=\"file\" name=\"file\" id=\"file\"/> 
<br />
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" onclick=\"setTimeout(function() { sendInfo(\"".$blah."\", \"".$test."\"); } ),1250);\" />
</form>";

echo "<h1>hello</h1>
<div id='form'>
<a href='#' onclick=\"popup('" . htmlentities($formcode) . "'); return false;\">
click here</a>
</div>";
```

This produces decent enough html code, however firebug gives me an error that I have an unterminated string lateral. I cannot find where this is. I understand the way I have done this is not ideal, but I am learning and do not know a better way at present. I appreciate any input

edit: OK, so the problem was that I had unterminated string literals, which were \n characters. I made the string into one line and it called the function correctly.

Is it not possible to break one echo statement into multiple lines?

Now the problem is with the html generated in the popupwindow. Some of the code is actually printed to the screen, why is this?

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data "><label for="file">Filename:</label><input name="file" id="file" type="file"> <br><input name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="setTimeout(function() { sendInfo(" type="submit"><h1>Well</h1>", "<h2>Done</h2>"); },1250);" /></form>
```

See the image [here](http://i44.tinypic.com/14t22k9.jpg):

Comment: Is your page publicly accessible? What's the URL?

Comment: Line 3 of your function you use `html` as the variable name, but you're passing `htmlcode`, is that just a typo?

Comment: yup just a typo, fixed. My page is not public, its just local.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is to open an HTML or PHP page that already has the form code in it, instead of opening `about:blank` and passing it dynamically.

There is no reason you should ever have to pass HTML into a Javascript function just so it can be directly written to document.

Comment: What about when there is over 20 variables?

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely have to keep the popup function as is, I found a solution with help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97578/how-do-i-escape-a-string-inside-javascript-inside-an-onclick-handler/97804#97804) to "[How do I escape a string inside javascript inside an onClick handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97578/how-do-i-escape-a-string-inside-javascript-inside-an-onclick-handler)".

```
<?php
$blah = "<h1>Well</h1>"; $test = "<h2>Done</h2>";
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="fetchlayers.js"></script>';
$formcode = '<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data ">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="setTimeout(function() { sendInfo(\\x27'.$blah.'\\x27, \\x27'.$test.'\\x27); }, 1250);" />
</form>';

echo "<h1>hello</h1>
<div id='form'>
<a href='#' onclick='popup(\"" . addslashes(str_replace("\n", ' ', $formcode)) . "\"); return false;'>
click here</a>
</div>";
?>
```

---

Before edit:

Maybe you can do it differently.

Javascript functions:

```
function popup(id, params){
    var html = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;

    if (params != undefined) {
        html = findAndReplaceStrings(html, params);
    }

    var child1 = window.open ("about:blank");
    child1.document.write(html);
    child1.document.close();
}

function findAndReplaceStrings(text, json) {
    for (var x in json) { 
        text = text.replace(x, json[x]);
    }
    return text;
}
```

HTML hidden code:

```
<div style="display:none;" id="process">
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data ">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/> 
<br />
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="setTimeout(function() { sendInfo('{param1}', '{param2}'); } ), 1250);" />
</form>
</div>
```

HTML link with json:

```
<a href="#" onclick="popup('process', {'{param1}':'<h1>Well</h1>', '{param2}':'<h2>Done</h2>'}); return false;">
click here</a>
```

Comment: My function popup function is relied on by too many other parts of the site, I would rather understand what the exact problem is with my relatively simple code.

Answer (score 0):

You must escape the carriage returns (\n) by doing

```
$formcode = str_replace("\n", "\\n", $formcode);
```

You also have to escape the quotes

```
$formcode = str_replace("'", "\\'", $formcode);
```

You can combines those two lines into a single one:

```
$formcode = str_replace(array("\n", "'"), array("\\n", "\\'"), $formcode);
```

Comment: Why use double slashes? Why do I need to escape the quotes? Where are carriage returns and why must I escape them?

Comment: I still get unterminiated string lateral.

Answer (score 0):

The submit button has an extra `)` which closes the setTimeout function too early. The specific spot is inside:

```
} ),1250
```

you should also probably think about using single quotes inside the php string to make it all easier to read. And because you're using double quotes you don't have to break out of the string to insert the content of the variables $blah and $test.

something like this should work:

```
$formcode = "...
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' 
onclick='setTimeout(function() { sendInfo(\"$blah\", \"$test\"); },1250);' />
...
```

";

EDIT:

looks like it's closing the onclick too early now. Matching these as the start and end quotes:

```
onclick=\"setTimeout(function() { sendInfo(\"
```

I changed the sendInfo line to the following, ran it and looks like it's working. The single quote is escaped here so it doesn't prematurely close the call to popup().

```
sendInfo(\'".$blah."\', \'".$test."\');
```

Comment: Ahh, I'm still getting an unterminated string lateral, trying exactly what you stated. I stoped breaking out of the string, and I removed the extra ).