# Escape quotes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, quotes, escaping

I'm outputting values from a database (it isn't really open to public entry, but it is open to entry by a user at the company -- meaning, I'm not worried about [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)).

I'm trying to output a tag like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="DoEdit('DESCRIPTION');">Click Me</a>
```

DESCRIPTION is actually a value from the database that is something like this:

```
Prelim Assess "Mini" Report
```

I've tried replacing " with \", but no matter what I try, Firefox keeps chopping off my JavaScript call  after the space after the word *Assess*, and it is causing all sorts of issues.

I must bemissing the obvious answer, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Anyone care to point out my idiocy?

Here is the entire HTML page (it will be an [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) page eventually, but in order to solve this I took out everything else but the problem code)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="DoEdit('Preliminary Assessment \"Mini\"'); return false;">edit</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a good idea to make your `onclick` event attachment unobtrusive and to move all of your database information into a data island.  Things will be cleaner and you'll actually get some sort of syntax error when your strings are escaped wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How do I escape a string inside JavaScript code inside an onClick handler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97578/how-do-i-escape-a-string-inside-javascript-code-inside-an-onclick-handler)*.

Comment: You can also use escape("string") and unescape("string") jquery methods

Answer (score 242, accepted):

You need to escape the string you are writing out into `DoEdit` to scrub out the double-quote characters. They are causing the `onclick` HTML attribute to close prematurely.

Using the JavaScript escape character, `\`, isn't sufficient in the HTML context. You need to replace the double-quote with the proper XML entity representation, `&quot;`.

Comment: Right, but wouldn't that be this?
<a href="#" onclick="DoEdit('Preliminary Assessment \"Mini\"'); return false;">edit</a>
I tried that, and it is still screwing up.  This has got to be a simple WTF but for the life of me, I can't see it.

Comment: Is there any built-in JavaScript function that would escape the double quotes ?
Apart from 'quo"'.replace('"', '&quot;') I can't find anything.

Comment: It's not a javascript issue, it's an HTML/XML encoding issue: you can't have double-quote characters inside an attributes value w/o escaping them... otherwise browsers/parsers think you're ending the attribute value declaration.

Comment: example replacement code: `'mystring'.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');`

Comment: in the previous comment there is an extra quote. The code that works is 'mystring'.replace(/'/g, '&quot;');

Comment: I know this is an old question, but why not simply use encodeURIComponent() / decodeURIComponent() -- to my knowledge they do exactly what you want and have been around since Armstrong walked on the moon or thereabouts i.e. all browsers support it.

Comment: @Adergaard, nope. Those are for a _third_ escape scheme used by HTTP in URLs.  `encodeURIComponent('"') == '%22'` (URI [includes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1984225/673991) URL).

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone Well, in my usecase it works perfectly. I have data-attributes that need to contain user generated text and when using my suggestion it works like a charm from mandarine chinese to danish with all 14 excalmation points used.

Comment: @AgustinLopez I don't see an extra quote in Joshua Burns' answer - just a double quote instead of a single quote.

Answer (score 116):

`&quot;` would work in this particular case, as suggested before me, because of the HTML context.

However, if you want your JavaScript code to be independently escaped for any context, you could opt for the native JavaScript encoding:
`'` becomes `\x27`
`"` becomes `\x22`

So your onclick would become:
`DoEdit('Preliminary Assessment \x22Mini\x22');`

This would work for example also when passing a JavaScript string as a parameter to another JavaScript method (`alert()` is an easy test method for this).

I am referring you to the duplicate Stack Overflow question, *[How do I escape a string inside JavaScript code inside an onClick handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97578)*.

Comment: Thank you! Yours is the more correct answer because it is native JavaScript regardless of context.

Comment: This is the correct answer, although in an HTML context using `&quot;` will, of course, work.

Comment: Note that `&quot;` is required in input values, i.e., `<input value="\x22quoted string\x22">` will not work.

Comment: @10basetom naturally, JavaScript escaping only works in a JavaScript context, like event handlers (`onclick="..."`). The value of a `value` attribute is not being processed within a JavaScript context, only within an HTML context.

Comment: replacement code: `'mystring'.replace(/"/g, '\\x22').replace(/'/g, '\\x27')`

Answer (score 34):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="DoEdit('Preliminary Assessment &quot;Mini&quot;'); return false;">edit</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 28):

Folks, there is already the `unescape` function in JavaScript which does the unescaping for `\"`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str="this is \"good\"";
    document.write(unescape(str))
</script>
```

Comment: A combination of "escape"/"unescape" did what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: escape/unescape are deprecated. although encodeURI does more than just quotes. http://gotochriswest.com/blog/2011/05/23/escape-unescape-deprecated/

Answer (score 14):

This is how I do it, basically `str.replace(/[\""]/g, '\\"')`.

```js
var display = document.getElementById('output');
var str = 'class="whatever-foo__input" id="node-key"';
display.innerHTML = str.replace(/[\""]/g, '\\"');

//will return class=\"whatever-foo__input\" id=\"node-key\"
```

```html
<span id="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that HTML doesn't recognize the escape character. You could work around that by using the single quotes for the HTML attribute and the double quotes for the onclick.

```
<a href="#" onclick='DoEdit("Preliminary Assessment \"Mini\""); return false;'>edit</a>
```

Comment: Yikes.  I was wondering why I naturally resorted to using ' for the attribute in the past.  I just never delved into it all that deeply.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're assembling the HTML in Java, you can use this nice utility class from Apache commons-lang to do all the escaping correctly:

> org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils
>  Escapes and unescapes
>   Strings for Java, Java Script, HTML, XML, and SQL.

Comment: I use org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(text) to construct methodExpression in Java. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please find in the below code which escapes the single quotes as part of the entered string using a regular expression. It validates if the user-entered string is comma-separated and at the same time it even escapes any single quote(s) entered as part of the string.

In order to escape single quotes, just enter a backward slash followed by a single quote like: **\’** as part of the string. I used jQuery validator for this example, and you can use as per your convenience.

Valid String Examples:

'Hello'

'Hello', 'World'

'Hello','World'

'Hello','World',' '

'It\'s my world', 'Can\'t enjoy this without me.', 'Welcome, Guest'

**HTML:**

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label class="control-label">
            String Field:
        </label>
        <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
            <input type="text" id="stringField"
                   name="stringField"
                   class="form-control"
                   autocomplete="off"
                   data-rule-required="true"
                   data-msg-required="Cannot be blank."
                   data-rule-commaSeparatedText="true"
                   data-msg-commaSeparatedText="Invalid comma separated value(s).">
        </div>
    </td>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
     /**
 *
 * @param {type} param1
 * @param {type} param2
 * @param {type} param3
 */
jQuery.validator.addMethod('commaSeparatedText', function(value, element) {

    if (value.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    var expression = new RegExp("^((')([^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\])*)[\\w\\s,\\.\\-_\\[\\]\\)\\(]+([^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\])*)('))(((,)|(,\\s))(')([^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\])*)[\\w\\s,\\.\\-_\\[\\]\\)\\(]+([^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\])*)('))*$");
    return expression.test(value);
}, 'Invalid comma separated string values.');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can copy those two functions (listed below), and use them to escape/unescape all quotes and special characters. You don't have to use jQuery or any other library for this.

```
function escape(s) {
    return ('' + s)
        .replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
        .replace(/\t/g, '\\t')
        .replace(/\n/g, '\\n')
        .replace(/\u00A0/g, '\\u00A0')
        .replace(/&/g, '\\x26')
        .replace(/'/g, '\\x27')
        .replace(/"/g, '\\x22')
        .replace(/</g, '\\x3C')
        .replace(/>/g, '\\x3E');
}

function unescape(s) {
    s = ('' + s)
       .replace(/\\x3E/g, '>')
       .replace(/\\x3C/g, '<')
       .replace(/\\x22/g, '"')
       .replace(/\\x27/g, "'")
       .replace(/\\x26/g, '&')
       .replace(/\\u00A0/g, '\u00A0')
       .replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
       .replace(/\\t/g, '\t');

    return s.replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');
}
```

Comment: not working for me. it can't escape double quotes

Answer (score 1):

I have done a sample one using jQuery

```
var descr = 'test"inside"outside';
$(function(){
   $("#div1").append('<a href="#" onclick="DoEdit(descr);">Click Me</a>');       
});

function DoEdit(desc)
{
    alert ( desc );
}
```

And this works in Internet Explorer and Firefox.

Comment: Of course it does, because you aren't putting it directly in the attribute.  To use your method, I'd have to create an array of JS strings, then do an arbitrary number of $("#divxxx")... assignments.  Less than optimal, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Escape whitespace as well. It sounds to me like Firefox is assuming three arguments instead of one.  `&nbsp;` is the non-breaking space character.  Even if it's not the whole problem, it may still be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape quotes with double backslashes.

This fails (produced by PHP's [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)):

```
<script>
  var jsonString = '[{"key":"my \"value\" "}]';
  var parsedJson = JSON.parse(jsonString);
</script>
```

This works:

```
<script>
  var jsonString = '[{"key":"my \\"value\\" "}]';
  var parsedJson = JSON.parse(jsonString);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May well be an exception, but recently I had to use this in a project:

```
elem.textContent.replace(/'/g, '\\\x27')
```

In this a11y bookmarklet:
[Highlighting image alt text](https://codepen.io/2kool2/pen/JjzampJ)

Probably due to being processed twice plus the bookmarklet requiring its own double quotes.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the escape() and unescape() jQuery methods. Like below,

Use `escape(str);` to escape the string and recover again using `unescape(str_esc);`.

Comment: Use of the `escape()` function is discouraged. Use `encodeURI()` or `encodeURIComponent()` instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape