# Java script : double quote text issue

Tags: javascript, html, double-quotes

I have a link which has `navigateToBusiness("check & ' "")`. Due to this double quote, script is not getting called. The value passed `check & ' "` is dynamic.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *escape* special characters with a leading `\`

```
navigateToBusiness("check & \' \"")
```

Comment: Thank for your response Andy. As the passed value is dynamic (from java), I tried `name.replace("\"","\\\"").replace("'", "\'")`. But still it generated as `check & ' "`. Do you have any idea? if so, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to escape the quote,

Read more here: [Escape quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/javascript-escape-quotes)

Hopefuly this helps