# Escape double quotes and other special characters in js

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I have something like in java

```
stringBuffer.append("<a onclick=\"javascript:setPName('"+StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(tmpResult)+"');\"><small> "+StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(tmpResult)+"</small></a>");
```

While checking the same on Console of Firebug it comes correctly. But I get the following when I check from IE developer tools:

`<A onclick="javascript:setPName('TEST\" AKHIL?);?><SMALL>TEST\"AKHIL</SMALL></A>`

Problem is that browser is not still recognizing it.
I had used StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript to escape single quotes but it does not work for double quotes.

Comment: What is that `javascript:` doing? It is a pointless [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) as there is no loop to break or continue from.

Comment: Check out [this][1] post.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/javascript-escape-quotes

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using `"` characters in *an HTML attribute value* delimited with the same character.

```
onclick="javascript:setPName('TEST\" <!-- attribute value ends here -->
```

The JavaScript is irrelevant.

You need to escape for HTML (`&quot;`) not JS.

You could avoid the problem entirely by writing [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Change ['] to ["], try and see. (Please remove "javascript:")

```
stringBuffer.append("<a onclick=\"setPName(\""+StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(tmpResult)+"\");\"><small> "+StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(tmpResult)+"</small></a>");
```

Or set the value into attribute (param).

```
stringBuffer.append("<a param=\""+StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(tmpResult)+"\" onclick=\"setPName(this.getAttribute('param'))\"><small> "+StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(tmpResult)+"</small></a>");
```

Comment: Then the onclick attribute will have the value `javascript:setPName(` which will make the problem worse!