# Third level of quote escaping in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-tools

I'm going to preface this with: "I know this is bad practice and an ugly hack (and I'm sorry) but..."

I'm using jQuery TOOL's tooltip widget to display a tooltip on an html element when the user hovers over it. With this widget you add the tooltip's html to the element's `title` attribute.

Inside of that html I have an element onto which I want to bind an inline `onclick` event handler.

Unfortunately I've run into too many layers of quotes to pass a parameter to the function I'm trying to call.

I have something like this:

```
<div title="<div onclick='myFunction(_____)'>My tooltip content</div>">My element</div>
```

This works if I need to pass an integer to `myFunction` since it doesn't need another set of quotes. Unfortunately I want to pass a string to `myFunction`. How can I further escape this string parameter so that it doesn't close the `onclick` or the `title` string?

Comment: Check out a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/javascript-escape-quotes

Comment: Thanks @wilsjd, that indeed is a working solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside of HTML attributes, you should encode quotes as HTML entities, e.g.:

```
<div title="This says &quot;Hello!&quot;">
    Hello!
</div>
```

Comment: This worked. Can you explain if this is a part of HTML that allows `&quot`s to be run as regular quotes in a JavaScript function or if this is some magic being done by jQuery TOOLs or if it's something else?

Comment: It's unrelated to JavaScript. This is just the way you would escape a double quote within a double-quoted HTML attribute. It's comparable to something like `alert("This says \"Hello\"")` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to my particular problem. Not sure if this works in the general case or if jQuery TOOLs is doing something magical to unescape my string but I ended up escaping with `&quot;` and it did evaluate into valid Javascript that was executed.

Something like this:

```
<div title="<div onclick='myFunction(&quot;_____&quot;)'>My tooltip content</div>">My element</div>
```

I don't really understand how this is working to be honest. Would love if someone could clarify what part of the process is changing those `&quot;`s into actual functional quotes.