# Replace simple quote and double quote

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a variable in my MySQL database. I want this variable to handle both simple and double quotes.

For example:

```
$variable = "I'm happy" or $variable = I'm happy or  $variable = "I am happy"
```

In my DB, the first example is this: `"i'm happy"` and that works for me. The problem is now on my JS function because I want to call my data:

```
nameFolder = "<?php echo $variable ; ?>"
```

But, if `$variable = "I'm happy"`, I've got double `""` so I get a JS error. And if I put single quote, the problem is the same with another case.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to escape your quotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/javascript-escape-quotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to echo data to JavaScript is to use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
var nameFolder = <?php echo json_encode($variable); ?>;
```

**N.B.:** There shouldn't be any surrounding quotes, function will handle that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
nameFolder = "<?php echo str_replace('"', '\"', $variable); ?>"
```