# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier with xpath

Tags: xpath

i am learning xpath, and i am trying to get some data from html usint xpath

i found that google chrome has a option to "copy xpath" and it works nice

but doesnt work to this exemple

```
<div id="site-main">
    <header class="main" role="banner">some divs      </header>
</div>
```

i use this on google chrome console

```
$x("//*[@id="site-main"]/header")
```

and return "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"
i dont see anythin wrong...do you?

Comment: Your XPath string ends at the `"` sign ... check out SO's syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$x("//*[@id="site-main"]/header")
            ^         ^
```

The marked quotes cause the error — in fact, the string is terminated right after `=`.

You have to escape the quotes inside the XPath expression. The way of escaping depends on the language you are using. If it's Javascript, then it would be with `\`:

```
$x("//*[@id=\"site-main\"]/header")
```

Also have a look on this question: [Escape quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/javascript-escape-quotes)

Answer (score 2):

You can use single quotes in the xpath query:

```
$x("//*[@id='site-main']/header")
```