# How can I quote text that's already inside a single and double quote?

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
'<textarea data-ng-show="modal.showPreview == 'Source'"  >'
```

How can I quote the word Source? I tried single quotes but that does not work.

Comment: I think you should have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/javascript-escape-quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the double quotes with `Backslash (\)`

Your code won't work as intended because, as soon as the browser encounters the first double quote, it will think that the string has finished.

You can refer to this: [JavaScript Escape Characters](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_escape_characters.cfm)

How about this:

```
'<textarea data-ng-show="modal.showPreview == \"Source\"" >'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use escaped double quotes:

```
'<textarea data-ng-show="modal.showPreview == \"Source\"">'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `backslash \`

```
'<textarea data-ng-show="modal.showPreview == \"Source\""  >'
```