# javascript override ' in document.write

Tags: javascript

I have a silly question but important for me. How to override ' in document.write in javascript? For example:

```
      document.write('Sent's Lois');
```

You see the problem is part Sent's   -'s-   because javasript considere it as the end Lois'...
It is a problem for me I was trying:

```
       document.write('Lois');
       document.write('s Lois');
```

But that's not it because you get  document.write('Sent s Lois'); and you missing Sent's again..... Any help please......

Comment: "Beside regular, printable characters, special characters can be encoded using escape notation." From [MDN String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [escape quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/javascript-escape-quotes)

use `\'`

```
document.write('Sent\'s Lois');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
 document.write("Sent's Lois");
```

Comment: you also can try `document.write('Sent\'s Lois');`

Comment: Yes we can but this gets quite messy when we have to escape multiple quotes in a single string.

Comment: there are cases and cases.

Comment: And we have alternates and alternates :)

Comment: yep. I never said otherwise. 

Well..What was marked as answer? o/

Comment: Well that answer fits user's needs so got marked as answer, but may be time or later he have to come to the alternate ;)

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is *escaping quotes*. Use the back-slash to do so:

```
document.write('Sent\'s Lois');
```