# HTML in HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I embed large HTML tags into this scenario?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            window.showim = function(src) {
                $("#divcont1").html(src);
            };
        });
```

Instead of `<h1>test</h1>` I need to insert large html content

```
<span class="spcusr" onclick="showim('<h1>test</h1>');">click me</span>

      <div id="divcont1"></div>
```

My Large HTML Content Sample

```
<div style="width:976px; height:576px; overflow:hidden; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image:url(MASTER.jpg)">
<table style="cursor:pointer;">
  <tr height="144">
    <td width="485"  onclick="window.location='#';">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="485" onclick="window.location='#';">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="144">
    <td onclick="window.location='#';">&nbsp;</td>
    <td onclick="window.location='#';">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="144">
    <td onclick="window.location='#';">&nbsp;</td>
    <td onclick="window.location='#';">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="144">
    <td onclick="window.location='#';">&nbsp;</td>
    <td onclick="window.location='#';">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

My main problem is at double quotes and quotes. Beacuase onclick="showim('`this started with single quotes and no more quotes allowed inside`')"; So, what to do in this situation? Thanks

Comment: You can escape the single quotes.

Comment: Take a look at html string [encoding and decoding](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp) methods of javascript.

Comment: An attribute is not a good place for storing HTML content. That's **anti-pattern**. You should consider using a templating library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Escape Quotes that go deeper than " and '.

This here, may help you:
[Escape quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/javascript-escape-quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotes before doing anything in the function.

```
window.showim = function(src) {
    src = src.replace(/'/g, "\'");
    src = src.replace(/"/g, '\"')
    $("#divcont1").html(src);
};
```