# Javascript parameter passing single apostrophe

Tags: javascript

I'm inserting content with js, that includes an onclick call to a function. This function passes a parameter which contains a database entry, which could contain a `'` .

```
var action = '<a href="#" class="facebook-share" onclick="facebookWallPost(\' '+name+'\')">Share</a>';
```

Trouble is that when name contains a single apostrophe it breaks the function call. I've tried doing a string replace on name to replace `'` with `&#39;` but this seems to still be converted back to a `'` by the browser.

Any idea how I can get around this?

Comment: Escape with slashes? `\'`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Javascript escape quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/javascript-escape-quotes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use escape() or after JavaScript version 1.5. use encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent() instead.

Comment: Cheers, I've used escape to pass it, and then unescape() in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write code by mashing strings together with other code. You've got JavaScript inside HTML inside JavaScript and it is a recipe for headaches.

Use DOM manipulation instead.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "#"; // You should use a button instead of a link to the top of the page
a.className = "facebook-share";
a.addEventListener('click', function () {
    facebookWallPost(name);
});
a.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode('Share');
);
```