# Undefined local variable or method ajax render partial rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, undefined, partial-views

I'm trying to add ajax to my comment form submission and I've run into an error when I'm trying to render a partial and I don't know how to solve it. I have everything set up properly and comments get created fine. But then I try to render the partial for the comments and I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `each' for #<#<Class:0xae4d760>:0xae59a78>
```

My **create.js.erb**

```
$("#comm_form_wrap").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "statuses/comment_form") %>");
$('#comment_box').val('');
$("#comments_wrap").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "statuses/comments") %>")
```

When I try to render `statuses/comments` is causing the error.

Here's my **partial:**

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div class="com_con">
        <%= Rinku.auto_link(comment.content).html_safe %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

So then I tried passing the variables like this

```
$("#comments_wrap").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "statuses/comments", :locals => {:comment => comment}) %>")
```

but it gives this error

```
undefined local variable or method `each' for #<#<Class:0xae4d760>:0xae59a78>
```

Not sure what I'm missing here, I'm sure it's something small. Can anyone help me?

**View**

```
<% if member_signed_in? %>
    <div id="comm_form_wrap">
        <%= render "comment_form" %>
    </div>

    <div id="comments_wrap">
        <%= render "comments" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

****Edit****

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_member!
before_filter :load_commentable
before_filter :find_member

def index
   redirect_to root_path
end

def new
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new
end

def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.member = current_member
    respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.save
          format.html { redirect_to :back }
          format.json
          format.js
        else
          format.html { redirect_to :back }
          format.json
          format.js
        end
    end 
end

def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.member == current_member || @commentable.member == current_member
          @comment.destroy
          format.html { redirect_to :back }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to :back, alert: 'You can\'t delete this comment.' }
        end
    end 
end

private

def load_commentable
    klass = [Status, Medium, Project, Event, Listing].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"] }
    @commentable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
end

def find_member
    @member = Member.find_by_user_name(params[:user_name])
end 

end
```

**statuses_controller**

```
def show
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @status
    @comments = @commentable.comments.order('created_at desc').page(params[:page]).per_page(15)
    @comment = Comment.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { redirect_to profile_path(current_member) }
      format.js
    end
end
```

**Logs**

```
Processing by StatusesController#show as HTML
    Parameters: {"id"=>"86"}
    [1m[35mMember Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."user_name" IS NULL LIMIT 1
    [1m[36mStatus Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "statuses".* FROM "statuses" WHERE "statuses"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "86"]]
    [1m[35mComment Load (2.0ms)[0m  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = 86 AND "comments"."commentable_type" = 'Status' ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
    [#<Comment id: 82, content: "and why not try again ha", commentable_id: 86, commentable_type: "Status", member_id: 1, created_at: "2014-06-26 06:27:05", updated_at: "2014-06-26 06:27:05">]
    [1m[36mMember Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1[0m
    [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
    [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = 86 AND "comments"."commentable_type" = 'Status'[0m
    Rendered statuses/_comment_form.html.erb (8.0ms)
    [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "members".* FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
    Rendered statuses/_comments.html.erb (95.0ms)
    Rendered statuses/show.html.erb within layouts/application (406.0ms)
    Rendered layouts/_query.html.erb (108.0ms)
    Rendered search/_search.html.erb (22.0ms)
    Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (592.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2956ms (Views: 2312.1ms | ActiveRecord: 10.0ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Show your controller code.

Comment: @MikeManfrin I edited the question and added the controller

Comment: That view file belongs to which action? You don't have `@comments` defined anywhere in your controller.

Comment: Your controller doesn't define `@comments` anywhere, so this is doomed to fail. You need to actually define that variable for your views to have access to it.

Comment: Sorry that's defined in my status show controller. I added the edit

Comment: Is that view file belongs to `show` action?

Comment: Yeah the view belongs to the show action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is your partial is calling `@comments.each`:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
```

2 issues:

> 1. `@comments` doesn't exist
> 2. Partials need to use `local` variables (they can't rely on `@instance` vars)

--

**Partials**

You'll be best doing this:

```
<%= render partial"statuses/comments", collection: @comments, as: comment %>
```

There is a little-known piece of functionality in Rails' partials which allows you to basically "reload" the partial for [each member of a collection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html#class-ActionView::PartialRenderer-label-Rendering+a+collection+of+partials).

The reason this is important is because it cuts out a LOT of code from your partial. If you use the partial I posted above, you'll only need this code *inside* the partial:

```
#app/views/statuses/_comments.html.erb
<div class="com_con">
    <%= Rinku.auto_link(comment.content).html_safe %>
</div>
```

If you set the correct `@instance variable`, and pass it into the `collection` option of the `partial`, Rails will basically reload the partial in a loop, like you have with the `.each` loop now

This will also work for singular items:

```
<%= render partial: "statuses/comments", object: @comment, as: comment %>
```

--

**Instance Variable**

The second issue is the setting of your `instance variable`

In your controller, you are not setting the `@comments` instance variable. This means you cannot load the contents of this variable into your view, consequently causing an issue like you've got

The way to fix this is very simple - use `@instance variables` you have set in your controller!

--

**Escape**

You may also need to look at how to [`escape` quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/javascript-escape-quotes) in your JS:

```
$("#comments_wrap").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => \"statuses/comments\", :locals => {:comment => comment}) %>")
```

I'm not sure if this is applicable in this case, but I *do* know if you encapsulated quotes inside another set, you'll get errors from your JS

Comment: In my statuses_controller I have @comments defined in my show action because that's what my view belongs to. You can see it in my edit.

Comment: Sorry about that! Have you tried using the `collection:` method?

Comment: Yeah I tried the collection method but then I get this error `undefined local variable or method 'comment' for #<#<Class:0x928bf00>:0x6c6e130>`

Comment: Hmm it looks like although you're setting your `@comments` var - it's only populating with a `class` or something. Can you do a `Rails.logger.info( @comments.inspect() )` in your `statuses_controller` & post what that variable looks like?

Comment: Hmmm okay thanks for that! It seems you're getting back the variable. This is rather strange. How are you calling the var in the partial? Have you tried setting a local variable for use in the partial, rather than the instance var?

Comment: Yeah I do this: `<%= render "statuses/comments", :locals => { :comment => @comments } %>` and removed this from the partial: `<% @comments.each do |comment| %>` but I get undefined local variable or method 'comment'. Can't figure out what's wrong. If I use my original code everything displays fine it just throws an error everytime I try to render it using ajax.

Comment: **Don't use `@instance variables` in partials**. Stop calling `@comments` in your partial. Use the locally defined variable instead: `<%= render "statuses/comments", :locals => { :comments => @comments } %>` -> `<% comments.each do |comment| %>`

Comment: Getting this: `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56415/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-iamdhunt).

Comment: I finally got `collection` to work and now rendering the partial like you said `<%= render partial"statuses/comments", collection: @comments, as: comment %>` However, when I try to render the partial again through ajax like so: `$("#comments_wrap").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/comments', :collection => @comments, :as => :comment) %>")` nothing happens. I get no errors but upon inspection it says it's rendering this `$("#comments_wrap").html("")`. Do you know why this may be? Everything in the controllers is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above helped me solve this. Rendering the comments as a collection helped me render the partial through ajax and I also needed to define `@comments` in my `create` action in my `comments_controller` as well to ensure it doesn't render blank.