# Escape double quote in WCF rest

Tags: wcf, rest

We host a WCF RESTful service. There is one service that is of verb POST, and it is possible to pass in double quotes as part of the message.  This is causing issues. I tried the standard back slash to escape it, but that didn't work. Any suggestions?  Here is the request body:

```
{"GardenWidth":"16' 7"","GardenLength":"62", "GardenStyle":"General","PostalCode":"12345",}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the comma after "12345":

```
{
    "GardenWidth": "16' 7\"",
    "GardenLength": "62",
    "GardenStyle": "General",
    "PostalCode": "12345"
}
```

Comment: No, that's not it.  The problem is with the 16' 7".  If I remove the 7", then it works fine.  Also, like I said in my question, I tried to backslash the double quote, and that didn't work.  Thanks for the input, I do appreciate it.

Comment: In that case, try replacing 7" with `7&quot;`

Comment: For more clarification, it is likely an encoding issue on the HTML side that is preventing it from seeing the escape character properly. The issue is explained in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2004178/2675888).