# oprating on single single quote in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have asked this question before and it's really a simple question but I am still waiting for an answer.

I want string containing "'" single quote.

I know I can use double single quote to evade the problem but I don't want to use double single quotes.

Is there any solution I can use single quote in Javascript. I am saving value with single quote in cookies and operating on it in javascript.

Its really a simple functionality I don't know why the developer community do not know some simple solution to it

UPDATE: I don't want to use back slash since I don't have access to string source

Comment: please add some example code... What are you trying to do, what error you get and what you are expecting it to do? It is hard to answer just like that.

Comment: You can escape `'` like `\'`

Comment: did You try the escape character:
var x="bla bla \" bla";

Comment: just as simple for you to do some research on the web

Comment: I do not have access to value source. I can not put back slash before every single quote. there gotta be some other solution

Comment: The following works fine in "modern" browsers ... please add an example how you operate on strings ......:  var testStr = "That's a valid string";
alert(testStr);

var testStr = "'";
alert(testStr);

Comment: @slash4 Exactly like this. I know we can embed javascript in html. So I want similar solution.

Comment: @james-donnelly I have updated my question. It's not a duplication. I reject the solution offered in that question

Comment: @Alex one of the answers on that question answers that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6820024/1317805 (read the comments though).

Comment: @JamesDonnelly encodeURI will give me "St.%20John" 's instead of St. John''s.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `\` escape character:

This is valid code:

```
var testString = 'this could\'ve gone wrong, but it didn\'t';
```

You can replace them yourself with this line:

```
strInputString = strInputString.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
```

This will escape all existing single quotes for you.

Comment: the problem is in string I do not know at what position the single quote appear

Comment: you can do a `string.replace("'", "\'")` (That is: replace [double-quote][single-quote][double-quote] by [double-quote][slash][single-quote][double-quote].

Comment: @Alex Edited my answer to reflect your comment.