# Trouble using single quote in a download link with an input

Tags: html, button, input, double-quotes

I'm trying to use a download link in an input type="button" that has an apostrophe, but it doesn't work the ways I've tryed and I can not use %27 in all links.

Eg:

```
<input value="Download" type="button" onclick='this.disabled=true;location.href="http://example/download/Don't.zip"; this.value="Starting.."'>
```

How can I make this works? Is that possible to also avoid this trouble if the download link has double quote (")? I need a solution that modifies the code itself instead of the link.

Comment: Can you add the actual html for your link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape quotes in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/escape-quotes-in-javascript)

Comment: @kurenaiKunai, this is more about encoding for URLs.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to encode the apostrophe for a URL, not HTML.

Take a look at this table: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

You'll see an apostrophe is %27 and a double quote is %22, so your URL would be:

```
http://example/download/Don%27t.zip
```

Comment: I'd like to modify the code instead of the link, so it could work with all links. Is that possible?

Comment: Most code libraries will have some kind of URL encoding library. What are you using to generate the link?

Comment: I use blogger, and the links comes from the CloudApp site. But I'd like to make things simpler, so the moderators could put the link directly without changing the link itself.

Comment: Does blogger not have some kind of link insert function like SO?

Comment: No, but if there is any alternative for this button I'll take it.

Comment: I don't know the blogger platform myself, getting this functionality is probably better asked on their support forum.