# javascript get unexpected error

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code dive error

```
$('.log').prepend('<div class="symbol sublog"> 
অনুগ্রহ করে একটি প্রতীক যুক্ত করুন (`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\;:",./<>?')  <br></div>');
```

I cant understand whats problem with (`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\;:",./<>?')

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/escape-quotes-in-javascript

Comment: Even if you think it isn't related to your problem, could you please edit the question and copy+paste the error message for us to see? Thank you! (Whatever, you forgot to escape the line feed and all the single quotes.)

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
(`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\;:",./<>?')
```

to

```
(\`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\;:",./<>?\')
```

you have single quotes, this is the problem. You have to escape them. Full answer:

```
$('.log').prepend('<div class="symbol sublog"> 
অনুগ্রহ করে একটি প্রতীক যুক্ত করুন (\`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\;:",./<>?\')  <br></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `'` with `"`. Single quote after `অনুগ্রহ করে একটি প্রতীক যুক্ত করুন` is breaking string.

```
$('.log').prepend('<div class="symbol sublog"> 
অনুগ্রহ করে একটি প্রতীক যুক্ত করুন ("~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\;:",./<>?")  <br></div>');
```

Comment: Though the line terminator/lf could be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="log">
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.log').prepend('<div class="symbol sublog"> অনুগ্রহ করে একটি প্রতীক যুক্ত করুন (`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\;:",./<>?`)  <br></div>');
});
```

[Execution](https://jsfiddle.net/56kbxgm4/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=56kbxgm4)

Answer (score 0):

You have single quotes at the end of

```
    (`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\;:",./<>?')
```

Hence replace ' with \' as given below

```
    $('.log').prepend('<div class="symbol sublog"> নুগ্রহ করে একটি প্রতীক যুক্ত করুন (`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\;:",./<>?\')  <br></div>');
```