# Additional Quotation marks besides " and '?

Tags: javascript, php

Are there additional quotation marks in Php, and JavaScript besides "..." and '...' in the case I need to nest them?

(The Alt+Number would be useful)

For example a Php echo:

```
echo "
  onClick='changeImage('example.jpg');'
";
```

I know I could escape the quotation marks , but I am wondering if there are another "level" of them that can be nested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape quotes in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/escape-quotes-in-javascript)

Comment: No, there isn't - not for php anyway, but if you need it, you might need to restructure your approach - you can always escape them though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Javascript**

You are in luck, in ES2015 specs, javascript now allows template literals using back ticks.

```js
console.log(`hello "world!" I'm doing well :)`);
```

**PHP**

Use *Nowdocs*. Don't use *Heredocs* unless you want to evaluate php code inside the string.
**Note:** someone already answered this, but I'll just reiterate to contain a whole solution.

```
echo <<<'STR'
`hello "world!" I'm doing well :)`
STR;
```

**Don't use Heredocs**

```
echo <<<STR
`hello "world!" I'm doing well :)`
STR;
```

Or

```
echo <<<"STR"
`hello "world!" I'm doing well :)`
STR;
```

Difference is the single quoted name. This is a *Heredoc*. It will evaluate PHP code denoted by ${*expression*} in your string.

**Don't use back ticks**

In PHP backticks will be evaluated as a shell command and return the output of said shell command.

Comment: What about php?

Comment: @rickdenhaan thanks for the catch. I'm so rusty on PHP nowadays.