# how to use single quote inside double quote while double quote already inside single quote?

Tags: javascript, php

I have string `$html = ' <button onclick="js_func(this, "in this point")"> submit </button>'` I want to send a string to js function I am trying with `'/'' string '\'` also with `"/"" string "\"` but didn't get the solution yet. Please guide me with correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just escape it with a backslash as simple as this:

```
$html = ' <button onclick="js_func(this, \'in this point\')"> submit </button>'
```

Answer (score 0):

With `\`==> ' < button onclick="js_func(this, \"in this point\")"> submit < /button>'

[Escape quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/escape-quotes-in-javascript)