# How to pass a variable to a function when the function is being called in a string (in JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building an Object using vanilla JavaScript and one of the key pairs in the Object is an edit button that has a function being called onclick. I want to pass a parameter to this function when building the object but I cannot  figure out the correct way to write the string.

You can see what I have tried in the code example below. I have not been able to get it to work properly.

```
new_projects.push({
      'Status': createStatusOrbs(project['Project Status'], 'Status'), 
      'Edit': "<i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' aria-hidden='true' onclick='getEditForm("+project['Project']+")'></i>",
      'Project Name': project['Project'],          
      'Last Update': moment(project['Last Update']).format("MMM Do YYYY")


    });
```

Comment: Escape the quotes or use a template literal. Possible duplicate of [Escape quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/escape-quotes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape the quote using backslash `\`. For example, if you want a string "Hello" (including quotes), you can do this:

```
var str = "\"Hello\"";
console.log(str); // "Hello"
```

The same is the case with single quotes too.

In your case, you can escape it like this:

```
if (project['Project Status'] !== "Closed") {
    new_projects.push({ 
        'Status': createStatusOrbs(project['Project Status'], 'Status'),
        // Notice the escaped quote
        'Edit': "<i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' aria-hidden='true' onclick='getEditForm(\'"+project['Project']+"\')'></i>", 
        'Project Name': project['Project'],
        'Last Update': moment(project['Last Update']).format("MMM Do YYYY") }); }

}
```

Or you can use template literals. For example, if you want to include a variable in a string, you can do this:

```
var x = 5;

// Notice that these are not single quotes. These are backticks
var y = `x = ${x}`;
console.log(y); // x = 5
```

In your case, you can use template literals as follows:

```
if (project['Project Status'] !== "Closed") {
    new_projects.push({ 
        'Status': createStatusOrbs(project['Project Status'], 'Status'),
        // Using template literal
        'Edit': `<i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' aria-hidden='true' onclick="getEditForm('${project['Project']}')"></i>`, 
        'Project Name': project['Project'],
        'Last Update': moment(project['Last Update']).format("MMM Do YYYY") }); }

}
```

Learn more about template literals [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Thank you for the information. The literals did not work for me but escaping out the variable did the trick!