# how to add a single quote string in the jquery append function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add elements to the HTML body, but I have a problem. the onclick function doesn't work because I blew the wrong one in the function. the following is the append code in my html

```
var html= "<button class='btn fab-success' type='button' onclick='openTabGeneral('tab_map', 'Web GIS', 'client/map/index.html', 'Get', 'yes')'>Click</button>";
$("body").append(html);
```

the result of that html code is

```
onclick="openTabGeneral(" 'tab_map'',''webgis'',''client/map/client="" map="" index.html'',''get'',''yes'')'=""
```

i want the result like this

```
onclick="openTabGeneral('tab_map', 'webgis', 'client/map/index.html', 'get', 'yes')"
```

please tell me how to change the code like this ^

Comment: it is much easier to create the node with `document.createElement()` instead of appending an html string... at least, I think, much more control over the element

Comment: you need to escape single quotes : \'tab_map\', for example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/escape-quotes-in-javascript)

Comment: In addition to @CalvinNunes point, it's much better practice to use unobtrusive event handlers instead of outdated `onclick` attributes. Then you avoid this issue entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short term fix is to escape the quotes within the attribute you create in the HTML string:

```js
var html = '<button class="btn fab-success" type="button" onclick="openTabGeneral(\'tab_map\', \'Web GIS\', \'client/map/index.html\', \'Get\', \'yes\')">Click</button>';
$("body").append(html);

function openTabGeneral() {
  console.log(arguments);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**However**, the much better approach is to build the Element manually, and to use an unobtrusive event handler on it which avoids the issue entirely. To do that you can use a delegated event handler and `data` attributes, like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  console.log($(this).data()); // all arguments
  console.log($(this).data('arg1')); // specific argument
});

$('<button />', {
  'class': 'btn fab-success',
  'type': 'button', 
  'text': 'Click',
  'data-arg1': 'tab_map',
  'data-arg2': 'Web GIS',
  'data-arg3': 'client/map/index.html',
  'data-arg4': 'Get',
  'data-arg5': 'yes' // this should probably be a boolean, not a string
}).appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```