# Handle apostrophe in input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have some js that adds an input field for a user:

```
var user = "O'Conner, John"    
b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + user + "'>";
```

When its inserted it looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="O" Conner, John'>
```

How do I amend this so it outputs like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="O'Conner, John">
```

I need the value to show the full name with the apostrophe. How can I get this to work?

Comment: This problem occurs because of the `'`, after the `O` symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the value first by replacing it with HTML entities.

As for `'` - It can either be `&rsquo;` or `&lsquo;`

```js
var user = "O'Conner, John";
user = user.replace("'", "&lsquo;");
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += "<input type='text' value='" + user + "'>";
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

There is also [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/escape-quotes-in-javascripthe%20string.) that already answers this question.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an element with JavaScript, you can pass the value to the input without any issue. Please check the below example:

```js
var user = "O'Conner, John"
var b = document.getElementById("b")
var input = document.createElement("input")
input.type = "text"
input.value = user;
b.appendChild(input)
```

```html
<body id="b"></body>
```