# Changing HTML with spans and symbols in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML and when a function is called, I want to change to text in a div that uses span.  The idea is to be a sort of customized alert.  I'm trying to use .innerHTML, but what I want to change has both quotations and span.  Is there a way that I can get this to update?

Current HTML:

```
<div id="messageBox" class="messageBox">
     <div id="picture"></div>
     <div id="messageArea">"I need to update this <span class="keyWord">code</span> and keep the 
          quotations and keywords!"
     </div>
</div>
```

This shows a box with a picture and

> "I need to update this **code** and keep the quotations and the
> keywords!"

The current javascript that I have is:

```
alertChange = document.getElementById("messageArea");
alertChange.innerHTML = ""This <span class="keyWord">code</span> needs to change!"";
```

It won't allow me to add the extra quotations or the span element.

The resulting text should be

> "This **code** needs to change!"

Comment: The [Escape quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/escape-quotes-in-javascript) is not correct. That one is about escaping quotes in the markup (attributes) not about escaping quotes to be used in a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1 - Backslash escape

Escape the double quotes within your HTML string with the backslash `\` character:

```js
alertChange = document.getElementById("messageArea");
alertChange.innerHTML = "\"This <span class=\"keyWord\">code</span> needs to change!\"";
```

```html
<div id="messageBox" class="messageBox">
     <div id="picture"></div>
     <div id="messageArea">"I need to update this <span class="keyWord">code</span> and keep the 
          quotations and keywords!"
     </div>
</div>
```

Further reading: [String - JavaScript | MDN#Escape Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_notation)

---

### Method 2 - Using template strings

Declare your string as a template literal by encapsulating it in backtick characters:

```js
alertChange = document.getElementById("messageArea");
alertChange.innerHTML = `"This <span class="keyWord">code</span> needs to change!"`;
```

```html
<div id="messageBox" class="messageBox">
     <div id="picture"></div>
     <div id="messageArea">"I need to update this <span class="keyWord">code</span> and keep the 
          quotations and keywords!"
     </div>
</div>
```

Further reading: [Template literals (Template strings) - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

---

### Method 3 - Single quote (`'`) encapsulation

In this specific case, since you haven't used single quotes anywhere in your string, you can simply declare the HTML string by encapsulating it in single quote characters. **Be forewarned that this will break if for whatever reason your text changes to include a single quote, which would then force you to escape them as detailed in Method 1.**

```js
alertChange = document.getElementById("messageArea");
alertChange.innerHTML = '"This <span class="keyWord">code</span> needs to change!"';
```

```html
<div id="messageBox" class="messageBox">
     <div id="picture"></div>
     <div id="messageArea">"I need to update this <span class="keyWord">code</span> and keep the 
          quotations and keywords!"
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you haven't found any duplicate for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Backslash \ to "escape" the special character (in your case the double quote symbol) like this

```js
alertChange.innerHTML = "\"This <span class=\"keyWord\">code</span> needs to change!\"";
```