# snowflake convert all columns to uppercase

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I have SP which looks at Info schema columns table and converts lower case columns to uppercase. Not able to wrap double codes around object.

```
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA_S.TBLNAME RENAME COLUMN ColName to COLNAME; //Won't work
ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA_S"."TBLNAME" RENAME COLUMN "ColName" to "COLNAME"; //this works

  select ('ALTER TABLE ' || TABLE_NAME || ' RENAME COLUMN "' || COLUMN_NAME || '" to "' || 
  UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) || '";') AS COL1 
  from information_schema.columns 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TBLNAME' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA_S'
  AND COLUMN_NAME != UPPER(COLUMN_NAME)  //this works in Snowflake
```

But within javascript, not able to use double quotes
javascript

```
    var table_control = " SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA,'.' ,TABLE_NAME, ' RENAME COLUMN ', COLUMN_NAME, ' to ', UPPER(COLUMN_NAME), ';') AS COL1 " 
        table_control += "  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS "
        table_control += " WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = " + String.fromCharCode(39)  + CURRENT_SCHEMA + String.fromCharCode(39)
        table_control += "   AND TABLE_NAME   = " + String.fromCharCode(39)  + CURRENT_TABLE + String.fromCharCode(39)
        table_control += "   AND COLUMN_NAME != UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) " ; //this works

    var table_control = " SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE "', TABLE_SCHEMA,'"."' ,TABLE_NAME, '" RENAME COLUMN "', COLUMN_NAME, '" to "', UPPER(COLUMN_NAME), '";') AS COL1 " 
        table_control += "  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS "
        table_control += " WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = " + String.fromCharCode(39)  + CURRENT_SCHEMA + String.fromCharCode(39)
        table_control += "   AND TABLE_NAME   = " + String.fromCharCode(39)  + CURRENT_TABLE + String.fromCharCode(39)
        table_control += "   AND COLUMN_NAME != UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) " ; //won't work
```

I get below,
JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in CONVERT_TBL_COLUMNS_UPPERCASE at ' var table_control = " SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE "', TABLE_SCHEMA,'"."' ,TABLE_NAME, '" RENAME COLUMN "', COLUMN_NAME, '" to "', UPPER(COLUMN_NAME), '";') AS COL1 " ' position 58

Bottom line - Need to concatenate objects(columns/schema/table) with double check so that i can rename column name uppercase dynamically thru javascript.

Please help, I'm missing something simple!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/escape-quotes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a JS UDF that will rename columns to uppercase.

It uses JS template strings to avoid problems with escaping quotes:

```js
create or replace procedure alter_table_to_uppercase(
    TABLE_SCHEMA string,
    TABLE_NAME string
) returns variant
language javascript as $$

var select_cols = `
    select column_name
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_catalog = current_database()
    and table_schema = '${TABLE_SCHEMA}'
    and table_name = '${TABLE_NAME}'
    and column_name != upper(column_name)
`;

var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: select_cols} );
var result_set1 = statement1.execute();

var cols_changed = [];

while (result_set1.next())  {
    var col_name = result_set1.getColumnValue(1);
    var alter_sql = `
        alter table ${TABLE_SCHEMA}.${TABLE_NAME}
        rename column "${col_name}" to "${col_name.toUpperCase()}"
    `
    snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: alter_sql}).execute();
    
    cols_changed.push(col_name);
}

return cols_changed;
$$
```

Testing it is easy:

```sql
create or replace table lowercased
as select 1 "a", 2 "b", 3 "c"
;

call alter_table_to_uppercase(current_schema(), 'LOWERCASED');
```

Comment: Recommend predicate removing columns forming part of clustering key to prevent failures.

Answer (score 0):

Some extra thoughts that might be helpful to solve your problem.

- [You cannot rename a column that is part of a clustering key.](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table.html#table-column-actions-tablecolumnaction) Meaning the query/stored proc will fail when it hit a column that's a clustering key.
- You can identify columns forming part of the clustering key by using the [System$Clustering_Information](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_clustering_information.html)
- [By default all column names are stored in uppercase if not in quotes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#unquoted-identifiers) So you're not really having to do anything. Adding quotes removes this default setting.
- You might be better solving the problem with a Session parameter like [QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-quoted-identifiers-ignore-case)