# How to pass an object inside a function call of a button in google app script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am having trouble parsing the object correctly. This code is on the backend.

```
var dummy = { rohan: "sharma" };
var downButton ='<input  type="button" value="Download" onclick="downloadFileAutomatically(\'' + JSON.stringify(dummy) +'\')" />';
```

On the front end this renders as

`<input type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs" value="Download JSON" onclick="downloadFileAutomatically('{" rohan":"sharma"}')"="">`

the `)"=""` section at the end is random and wrong.

On clicking this button the browser throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` which is expected behavior.

How should I handle the quotes hierarchy for this to work.

Comment: I'm not really sure where `)"=""` comes from, but to avoid syntaxError you would need to escape JSON string, please take a look:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2004178/2036169

Or you can JSON.stringify and base64 encode to avoid any formatting issues, of course it only applies if you can decode it in the function.

Comment: Consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including the code related to how the server-side string gets rendered client-side.

Comment: You need to do two things 1. Escape JSON string inside quotes (you can use built-in encodeURIComponent function) 2. Be sure whether you have  typed `=` by mistake

Comment: @Rhymondn Did some research. Google app script adds that to all the function calls in its sandbox rendering of javascript.

Comment: @Iamblichus Thanks for the guideline. There is unfortunately nothing else relevant that I can add. Someone who knows app script would have to make test this in their environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution

> Using string interpolation and encoded JSON string

```
var dummy = { rohan: "sharma" };
var downButton =`<input type="button" value="Download" onclick="downloadFileAutomatically('${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(dummy))}')"/>`;
```

Or for clarify

```
var dummy = { rohan: "sharma" };
var dummyEncoded = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(dummy))
var downButton =`<input type="button" value="Download" onclick="downloadFileAutomatically('${dummyEncoded}')"/>`;
```

It escapes single and double quotes of JSON data so it can be placed inside quotes. Use `decodeURIComponent()` to get orginal JSON string.

However you can escape JSON string by other means too.

**Tip:** You can use `event listeners` instead of `onclick` to make code and formatting less error-prone.

Comment: string interpolation doesn't work in app script but decoding encoding did the job