# How to fix this java script error handling single quote in the line

Tags: javascript

Hi I had a similar requirement as below and was 
curious to know to fix the issue.

Below is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Msg1(){
  var sd= document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = 'Thank's!';
  alert('-sd-'+sd);
}
function Msg2(){
  document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = 'Try messages 1 again...';
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="Msg1()" value="Show Message 1" />
<input type="button"  onclick="Msg2()" value="Show Message 2" />
<p id="myText"></p>
```

The `innerHTML` tag is throwing script error like

```
Webpage error details


Message: Expected ';'
Line: 29
Char: 64
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/j1007962/Desktop/spl.html
```

I was looking for the fix around `innerHTML` or better replace with something which would fix
this . Thanks

Comment: I dont want to replace the message in double quotes as this is dynamically generated one

Comment: This may help for dynamically generated one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97578/how-do-i-escape-a-string-inside-javascript-inside-an-onclick-handler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should escape your quotes.

Modify

```
var sd= document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = 'Thank's!';
```

To

```
var sd= document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = 'Thank\'s!';
```

Or use double quotes

```
var sd= document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = "Thank's!";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape the single quote

```
var sd= document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = 'Thank\'s!';
```

---

**Edit**

Let say we have some text coming from Server side or from a HTML tag. In that case we have a valid variable. So there is no need to change that variable.

```
<div id="div1">
    Thank's!
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function changeDivHTML()
{
    var innerText = document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML;

    alert( innerText );
}
```

OR if the text is coming from server via Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    success: function(data){
        alert( data.someStringValue );
    }
});
```

Comment: This works if the message is static .How do I work around if its coming from server side means dynamically the message gets changed

Comment: Lets say if it is coming from server side, Then it will automatically be a valid variable. means that it will contain the valid string. No need to change that image.