# Adding a C# variable to javascript

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following block of code in my header:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#target').readmytweet({
                'color': 'black',
                'search': 'from:' + <%= GetUserName() %>,
                'user': <%= GetUserName() %>,
                'width': 600,
                'tweets': 10,
                'speed': 25
            });
        })
    </script>

protected string GetUsername()
        {
            return "somestring..";
        }
```

However, I am getting an error message:

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control
>   contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Does anyone know how I can pass a C# variable from my code behind into this jQuery function without getting that error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For a dynamic string:**

That seems like it would work, try wrapping the code blocks with quotes, as such:

```
'<%= GetUserName() %>'
```

also you may have to use a `this` statement to access that method:

```
'<%= this.GetUserName() %>'
```

**For a static string:**

Declare your string as a public string in your aspx page:

```
public string UserName = "somestring..";
```

and access it via:

```
var userName = <%=this.UserName%>;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is [a well-known problem](http://romsteady.blogspot.com/2007/08/workaround-controls-collection-cannot.html) when trying to add controls to a page that contains code blocks.

A simple workaround is to use data binding expressions instead, i.e., to use `<%# ... %>` instead of `<%= ... %>`. Note that you will have to call `this.DataBind();` in your `Page_Load event` for this to work.

(BTW, remember that the code you insert in JavaScript [will need to be properly quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97578/how-do-i-escape-a-string-inside-javascript-inside-an-onclick-handler).)

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a server-side c# variable/property within an .aspx page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <% string username = Class.PropertName; %>
  var jsUsername = '<%: username %>';
</script>
```

Comment: 5 years later and nothing new in your answer. I recommend deleting this answer.