# Too many quotes within quotes -- what to do?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a section of code used by CKEditor on my website:

```
CKEDITOR.config.IPS_BBCODE          = {"acronym":{"id":"8","title":"Acronym","desc":"Allows you to make an acronym that will display a description when moused over","tag":"acronym","useoption":"1","example":"[acronym='Laugh Out Loud']lol[/acronym]", ...
```

If you scroll to the right just a little, you will see this:

```
"[acronym='Laugh Out Loud']lol[/acronym]"
```

I need to store all of the CKEditor code inside a javascript string, but I can't figure out how to do it because the string has both " and ' in it. See the problem? Furthermore, I don't think I can just escape the quotes because I tried doing that and the editor didn't work.

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: All your quotes are belong to quotes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/97578/102937 for escaping quotes in Javascript.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might try taking the string and injecting JavaScript escape codes into it. JavaScript can essentially use any unicode value when using the format: `\u####` - so, for a `'` character, the code is `\u0039`, and for the `"` character, the code is `\u0034`.

So - you could encode your example portion of the string as:

```
\u0034[acronym=\u0039Laugh Out Loud\u0039]lol[/acronym]\u0034
```

Alternatively, you could attempt to simply escape the quotes as in:

```
\"[acronym=\'Laugh Out Loud\']lol[/acronym]\"
```

The problem here occurs when you wind up with this kind of situation:

```
"data:{'prop1':'<a href="/url/here/">back\\slash</a>'}"
```

Which, when escaped in this manner, becomes:

```
"data:{\'prop\':\'<a href=\"/url/here/\">back\\\\slash</a>\'}\"
```

While this is somewhat more readable than the first version - de-serializing it can be a little tricky when going across object-spaces, such as a javascript object being passed to a C# parser which needs to deserialize into objects, then re-serialize and come back down. Both languages use \ as their escape character, and it is possible to get funky scenarios which are brain-teasers to solve.

The advantage of the `\u####` method is that only JavaScript generally uses it in a typical stack - so it is pretty easy to understand what part should be unescaped by what application piece.

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. you said you already tried to escape the quotes and it gave problems.
This shouldn't give problems at all, so try this:

```
$newstring = addslashes($oldstring);
```

Comment: There is no mention of PHP or PHP tag on this question, why would you suggest that?

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma - It was my fault.. I changed my question after posting

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use Unicode escape sequences. Just surround your string with double quotes, and put a backslash before any double quotes within the string.

```
var x = "\"[acronym='Laugh Out Loud']lol[/acronym]\"";
```