# How do I pass 2 PHP variables in a javascript function?

Tags: php, javascript

How do I pass 2 PHP variables in a javascript function?

This one is working

```
 echo '<button onClick = "count('.$increment.')">'.$counter.' </button>';
```

but when i do this

```
  echo '<button onClick = "count('.$increment.','.$pass.')">'.$counter.' </button>';
```

it does not work, what is the problem?

By the way these are the variables:

```
    $increment=5;
    $pass="sdfgd";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<button onClick = "count('.$increment.',\''.$pass.'\')">'.$counter.' </button>';
```

Comment: wow this works also..wow didnt know it was that easy thanks man

Answer (score 4):

Try this dude......

```
<button onClick = "count('<?php echo $increment ?>','<?php echo $pass ?>')"><?php echo $counter ?></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$pass` contains exactly `"sdfgd"` and with exactly I mean double quotes includes, this isn't a valid statement anymore, because your parser will find double quotes "too early" and them will close the `onClick` event attribute

After variable expansion:

```
echo '<button onClick = "count('5','"sdfgd"')">'.$counter.' </button>';
-------------------------------------^
```

Take a look to the arrow

## Edit

However, if you use a tool like [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) (if you run firefox), you can debug your code easily

Comment: so does that mean that currently there is no way i can input a string? how do i input a string defined variable like $pass.

Comment: @Andremalupet Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97578/how-do-i-escape-a-string-inside-javascript-inside-an-onclick-handler)

Comment: ill try this one..this is same from jsonencode right?uhmm..its weird that firebug is actually returning the variable value as undefined yet it has a variable and a value..sorry for asking..but what does that mean..thanks anyway men..you are a big help.

Answer (score 0):

The generated HTML code should look like this:

```
<button onClick = "count(5,sdfgd)">5 </button>
```

The variable sdfgd is most likely undefined, therefore undefined gets passed to your function.

If you want to pass a string you have to use quotes, so that the generated HTML looks like this:

```
<button onClick = "count(5,'sdfgd')">5 </button>
```